Generate token to fetch ADO workitems from Azure using federated credentials in ASP.NET Core MVC
I want to generate access token for VssOAuthAccessTokenCredential without secret/certificate by using only federated credentials in ASP.NET Core MVC.
var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential();

// Acquire a token for Azure DevOps
var tokenRequestContext = new TokenRequestContext(new[] { "https://dev.azure.com/.default" });
var token = await credential.GetTokenAsync(tokenRequestContext);


Prerequisites

Azure Identity SDK: Ensure that your project includes the
Azure.Identity package, which provides the DefaultAzureCredential
class.
Azure DevOps Permissions: Make sure the Azure AD application you're
using has the necessary permissions for accessing Azure DevOps.

Install Necessary NuGet Packages:

dotnet add package Azure.Identity
dotnet add package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common
dotnet add package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client

Example Code
using Azure.Core;
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class AzureDevOpsService
{
    private readonly string _organizationUrl;

    public AzureDevOpsService(string organizationUrl)
    {
        _organizationUrl = organizationUrl;
    }

    public async Task<VssConnection> GetAzureDevOpsConnectionAsync()
    {
        // Create a credential using DefaultAzureCredential
        var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential();

        // Define the scope for Azure DevOps
        var tokenRequestContext = new TokenRequestContext(new[] { "https://dev.azure.com/.default" });

        // Acquire the token for Azure DevOps
        var token = await credential.GetTokenAsync(tokenRequestContext);

        // Create the VssOAuthAccessTokenCredential using the acquired token
        var vssCredential = new VssOAuthAccessTokenCredential(token.Token);

        // Create the VssConnection using the organization URL and the OAuth credential
        var connection = new VssConnection(new Uri(_organizationUrl), vssCredential);

        return connection;
    }
}


I Tried but getting below error.
Azure.Identity.CredentialUnavailableException: 'DefaultAzureCredential failed to retrieve a token from the included credentials
Error Code: 3399614476
Error Message: SubError: consent_required V2Error: invalid_grant AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID '04f0c124-f2bc-4f59-8241-bf6df9866bbd' named 'Visual Studio'. Send an interactive authorization request for this user and resource. Trace ID: d93f59e1-cc49-4ce2-8f5e-8b8e7d550700 Correlation ID: d5af9b22-3937-4239-a906-d1e4e7b662bf
